# Android update SQLite DB schema?

Tags: android, sqlite

What is the best practice for updating the DB schema?  I could send a text file with the SQL commands.  The app could check the text file and execute the commands needed.  I am guessing then I will have a flag to indicate that the update has been done.  I havent found a way to delete a file in the asset folder from the app, which would be the best thing to do after the DB was updated.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will probably want to override

```
onUpdate(SQLiteDatabase db,int old Version,int newVerison)
```

The following tutorial can walk you through the process: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx

Comment: this looks good but what happens if a user doesnt update and skips a few versions.  So supposing they have version 1.  All is good. I use the onUpdate() on the version 2.  All is good here and I can put in the SQL commands in the code.  Then version 3 comes along, I wipe out the last updates and put in new ones, I assume.  This is all good except what happens to the person that never got version 2?

Comment: @Mark Worsnop: Your `onUpdate()` has to handle all scenarios. So, if you have schema revisions 1, 2, and 3, and you need to go from 1 to 3, one solution is to apply the 1->2 change, then the 2->3 change.

Comment: As @CommonsWare  sir mentioned, in `onUpdate()` method we should consider all conditions i.e. 1 -> 2 , 1 -> 3 , 2 -> 3 because we should not assume that all users have latest version

Answer (score 4):

> What is the best practice for updating the DB schema?

Use `SQLiteOpenHelper`. The only time you will be updating your schema is when you update the application. Whether you have the SQL commands in a file that you read in or just in your Java code is up to you.

> I am guessing then I will have a flag to indicate that the update has been done.

That is part of what `SQLiteOpenHelper` gives you.

> I havent found a way to delete a file in the asset folder from the app, which would be the best thing to do after the DB was updated.

That is not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned from others the SQLiteOpenHelper is the thing you are starting with.

Depending on your environment and requirements, [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) may be worth a look. It allows writing your update statements in a more structural way and is easier to use than plain SQL operations. I haven't used it for android, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the db schema use the following code in your SQLiteOpenHelper extended class. This will update the table structure and never lose your saved data from db,

```
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
    newVersion) {
      if (oldVersion < newVersion) 
      {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + "TABLE_NAME" + " TO " + 
        "NEW_TABLE_NAME");

        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + "TABLE_NAME" + " ADD COLUMN " + 
        "FIELD_NAME" + " INTEGER;");
      }   
    }
```

SQLite doesn't support removing or modifying columns.